# Bootstrap IE 8 and under

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

I've been reading for days on ways to fix IE8 and under for Bootstrap.

The Site:  www.sevensage.com/hueler

It works great in all other versions and all other browsers.  As soon as you hit IE8, it falls apart and reverts to a one column, mobile view.  Also, am not viewing this site locally, it is on my server.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/hueler-styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/component.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/print.css" type="text/css" media="print">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-ie.css">
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Any JSFiddle? fyi, IE8 will be forced upgraded to IE11 in Jan 2015

Comment: My apologies, no JSFiddle (though I will look into it!) Just the URL to the actual site: http://www.sevensage.com/hueler

On another note, you just made my night with the news about IE8 being force-upgraded!

Comment: @Raptor IIRC it is 2016, not 2015, and it is not "forced upgraded"; MS will simply stop providing support for older versions. Granted this will greatly accelerate the migration to IE11, but some consumer-facing websites may still choose to support old browsers.

Comment: @torazaburo oh yes, it's 2016. typo. IE will be automatically upgraded to 11 via Windows Update

Comment: What's `bootstrap-ie.css`? That's not part of Bootstrap...

Comment: Have you checked all of these limitations?: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie8-respondjs

Comment: bootstrap-ie.css is not a part of bootstrap, you are correct.  It's just a custom file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately respond.js doesn't work when the css file is on a different domain. However you can set it up so that it does work and it's not too difficult. Have a look at these instructions:

> Respond.js works by requesting a pristine copy of your CSS via AJAX,
>   so if you host your stylesheets on a CDN (or a subdomain), you'll need
>   to upload a proxy page to enable cross-domain communication.
>
> See cross-domain/example.html for a demo:
>
> Upload cross-domain/respond-proxy.html to your external domain Upload
>   cross-domain/respond.proxy.gif to your origin domain Reference the
>   file(s) via  element(s):
>
> ```
> <!-- Respond.js redirect location on local server -->
> <link href="/path/to/respond.proxy.gif" id="respond-redirect" rel="respond-redirect" />
>
> <!-- Respond.js proxy script on local server -->
> <script src="/path/to/respond.proxy.js"></script>
> ```

From the [Github repository](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond/blob/master/README.md#cdnx-domain-setup). This method works with the Bootstrap CDN.

Comment: Ah, I see.  So if I was using respond.js from the root of my site and not from a folder with a new website within my site, this would have worked by linking the way I was?

Essentially, once I moved this off the development part of my server an onto the client server's root, it would have functioned properly then, correct?

Okay, I think I'm picking up what you're laying down.  Thank you for your response!

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean but essentially respond.js has to be on the same domain as the css you are trying to apply it to. If it's not you have to use the workaround above. For example if you have respond.js on your domain (www.website.com/respond.js) and the bootstrap css on a different domain such as a cdn (netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap.css) then you would need to use the workaround above.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? If this answered your question you should mark it as accepted (big green checkbox next to the up/down arrows) so other users searching will see that this question has an answer.

Comment: Oh thanks! I'm pretty new around here.  I set the comment to answered, but I hadn't realized there was a check mark to check.

Answer (score 0):

So it appears linking to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

WILL NOT WORK for IE8, particularly if you're working on a cross-domain (site within your root site).

You MUST link to a local (mine is un-minifed) version of bootstrap CSS and respond.js or use the method described above by one of the commentators.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"> (linking directly)
```

Another tip, just in case you're having issues with how the styles load - make sure you load boostrap.css BEFORE you custom styles.

Cheers!